# Why I can call memcached from command line, but can't call from apache

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I can't call a memcached from apache.
when I called phpinfo() from command line I see the memcached and I can use it.
But when I called phpinfo() from apache, I don't see the memcached.

Cofiguration file path(php.ini) /etc (APACHE)

Configuration file path(php.ini)  /usr/local/etc/php/5.6 (COMMAND LINE)

What is the problem?
P.S. PhpIniDir I used, but nothing
P.P.S. my operating system is Mac OS

Comment: You probably have to edit the `/etc/php.ini` to reference memcached the same way `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` does

Comment: yes, I did a symlink

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards?

Comment: of course, I did it